# Win32/C can't display msg box right after CreateWindow

Tags: winapi, window, modal-dialog, messagebox

I'm creating my app window in code and I'm trying to show a message box as soon as the window exists. But I can't. I see only the newly created window, no msg box. If I quit the app by closing its window, the msg box suddenly appears, as if it were waiting in some queue, to be shown only when the app window is closed. Does the way I create the window somehow block modal msg boxes? Note: the MessageBox line is there just for testing. I'll take it out for normal use, as it would obviously interfere with the GetMessage loop.

```
//start relevant section of WinMain:
WNDCLASS wc={0};
wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
...
if (!RegisterClass(&wc) || !CreateWindow("mc", "mc", WS_POPUPWINDOW|WS_CAPTION|WS_VISIBLE, 100, 50, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL)) {
  Error("Can't create window");
  return 0;
}
ShowWindow(win, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
MessageBox(0, "Test", 0 ,0);
while (GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0)>0) {
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
//end relevant section of WinMain

long FAR PASCAL WindowProc(HWND h, UINT m, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM l)
{
    switch (m) {
        //process other messages
        case WM_CREATE:
            win=h;
            //init stuff, paint something in the main window
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(h, m, wParam, l);
}
```

Comment: Saving the return value of `CreateWindow` would be better than using a global variable.

Comment: I changed the "!CreateWindow..." part to "!(win=CreateWindow...)" and removed "win=h" from WM_CREATE. No change in behavior: still no msg box.

Comment: You are not posting your full WindowProc, or some other piece of code is missing. MessageBox contains a near identical GetMessage loop so it should not matter.

Comment: Went through WindowProc line by line and finally found the culprit. 3 lines: case WM_PAINT: return 0; break; a remnant of a past experiment. I thought naively that "return 0" will just skip the WM_PAINT block (like commenting it out), but of course it doesn't. It means: when you get a WM_PAINT message, do NOTHING. This screws up window display, of course. Had I thought this may be relevant to the problem I'd have included it here. Then again, had I known this were the problem, I'd have taken it out and not bothered people on SO in the first place. Thx for forcing me to re-analyze WindowProc.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not returning immediately from `WM_CREATE` like you're supposed to, but your window's entire lifetime is inside `CreateWindow`.  So MessageBox doesn't actually get called until your window is dead, and trying to pass `wnd` as the parent of the message box is an invalid argument (the window no longer exists).

You shouldn't call `DefWindowProc` for `WM_CREATE`.  You shouldn't have a message loop (i.e. `DispatchMessage`) inside `WindowProc` (exception: a message loop handling a modal dialog that is a child of the main window).

Re-entrancy of window procedures is something to avoid if possible.

Comment: DefWindowProc is outside the switch block, not part of WM_CREATE (see above). There's no DispatchMessage inside WindowProc, it's in WinMain (see above). I just added "MessageBox(0, "Test create", 0 ,0)" at the end of the "case WM_CREATE" block, just before "break". I see "Test create" msg box before the app window appears. This tells me that WM_CREATE finishes its job.

Comment: Just noticed: If I remove both the WS_VISIBLE flag from CreateWindow and the "ShowWindow(win, SW_SHOWNORMAL)" line (basically, if I create an invisible window), the "Test" msg box shows up. When I click OK on the msg box, I get an invisible app running. So it's the visibility of the main window that blocks the msg box.